# How to copy an AbstractMap

Tags: java

In my application I need a clone of an AbstractMap.I want to copy it with all the values and keys. Is it possible?

Comment: `Map<..,..> copy = new HashMap<..,..> (abstractMap);` ?

Comment: Do you want a shallow or deep clone?

Comment: @assylias, that will make a deep copy of the map, but not the entries :)

Comment: @mre I am not sure what the op wants to be honest (hence the question tag!).

Comment: Did I ask something wrong why the minus ???

Comment: Down-voting this question is not fair. There may be times when something that seems very obvious to somebody is not that obvious at all for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use clone() for an AbstractMap, unless it has been overridden as it has been for many built in collections.

It is usually easier to copy the Map.

```
Map<K,V> map2 = new XxxxMap<K,V>(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementations of the `Map` interface have constructors accepting another `Map`. This way you can copy the original map to another one.